# Microsoft Fakes can't find the `ICollection` and `IDictionary` interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

MS Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

I am learning *Microsoft Fakes Framework*. I have two assemblies `AcDbMng.dll` and `AcMng.dll` are written by other company (Autodesk). They use .Net Framework 2.0. I create new *Unit Test Project*, add these assemblies into my project, and through their context menu call the "*Add Fakes Assembly*". Now I launch my project building and get 128 errors... For example:

> It wasn't succeeded to find type or a name of a name space of
>   "`ICollection`" (perhaps, there is no directive of using or an assembly
>   reference). [c:\users\andrey\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\msfakes\obj\Debug\Fakes\adm\f.csproj] msfakes
>   c:\users\andrey\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\msfakes\f.cs
>   206092
>
> It wasn't succeeded to find type or a name of a name space of
>   "`IDictionary`" (perhaps, there is no directive of using or an assembly
>   reference). [c:\users\andrey\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\msfakes\obj\Debug\Fakes\adm\f.csproj] msfakes
>   c:\users\andrey\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\msfakes\f.cs
>   206119
>
> The modifier "`override`" is not valid for this item. [c: \ users \
>   andrey \ documents \ visual studio 2015 \ Projects \ msfakes \ obj \
>   Debug \ Fakes \ adm \ f.csproj] msfakes c: \ users \ andrey \
>   documents \ visual studio 2015 \ Projects \ msfakes \ f. cs 206119

Such error messages are not clear for me. I tried to change the target .Net Framework platform: .Net 4.6 and .Net 3.5, but I get the same messages.

`ICollection`, `IDictionary`, modifier "`override`"... I don't understand, what relation they have to these assemblies, because they are defined in the platform assemblies instead of `AcDbMng.dll` and `AcMng.dll`.

Anybody has idea about such behaviour?

**UPD**

Maybe Autodesk uses own interfaces with the same names and I am to add some additional assemblies of AutoCAD for *Microsoft Fakes Framework* using?

If I generate the fake only for `AcMng.dll` then I haven't errors. But if I generate the fake also for `AcDbMng.dll` then I get these problems. Also, at this case in the *Solution Explorer* I see the `AcMgd.17.2.0.0.Fakes` appeared, but I don't see something like `AcDbMgd.17.2.0.0.Fakes`:

[image]

**UPD2**

It is possible to download the `AcDbMgd.dll` file from [here](https://yadi.sk/d/pQ9EgQPTmdWMD).

**UPD3**

Theme is closed. More detailed info about the `fakes`-format is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708916.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try editing the `AcDbMgd.fakes` and `AcMgd.fakes` files with something like

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
  <Assembly Name="AcDbMgd" Version="..."/>
  <StubGeneration>
    <Clear/>
  </StubGeneration>
  <ShimGeneration>
    <Clear/>
    <Add FullName="your class of concern"/>
  </ShimGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

You're restricting the classes that get generated and explicit deciding which classes do.  When I run into problems like you're having, if I limit the classes that get generated, I have better luck.  It's hard to give a more specific answer without being able to recreate it myself.

Comment: Thank you, @doobop. I will try your advice. Also I added **UPD2** into my theme. It contains the link to `AcDbMgd.dll`file.